# Design Pattern for handling different types of instructions to make different types of method calls

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have seen many threads on the internet but I am not able to fit any pattern for my problem.

I want to analyze an instruction which can call different types of calls. For example,

Instruction types, for example, can be type-1, type-2 etc. and called method can be method1, method2 etc. So there is a kind of many-to-many relationship.

```
instType1 method1
instType2 method1
instType2 method3
instType3 method3 
...
```

I have thought about one handler for each instruction type and each method type but either way, I will have to write checks for the other thing in each handler. For example, in instruction-type1-Handler, I will have to check if called type is method1 or method2 etc.

Is there any easy or cleaner way to do this?

**Edit-1**

A concrete example would be

```
invoke-virtual v7, v4, Ljava/io/FileOutputStream;->write
```

Here I can have different types of invoke-* calls and different set of Java API calls.

I want to write a separate handler for each invoke-type and called-API type. And suppose if I give this instruction to invoke-virtual-handler, it will have to check for call type first and then process it. And same logic will be in each handler.

Is there any way to avoid the same code in different handlers?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this problem. But on which object are you calling the methods? Could you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have no idea what this question is asking. @Junaid, could you give a concrete example of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Please have a look on the Edit portion.

Comment: It would be best if you explained some more. Who is handling the calls? Are calls passed to the instruction? Does instruction handle the calls? I've read a couple of times and I can't quite grasp your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Kayaman in regards to the [Command pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/command_pattern.htm) design. Nonetheless, I think it's good that you know there's another way as well, through Java's Reflection API. Assuming that what you want is to be able to do the following:

```
evaluate(instruction, call);
```

Without having to have in the method **evaluate(...)** a whole bunch of **switches** or **if elses**. I'd suggest using Java's API reflection, meaning that you'd be able to add as many instructions and calls as you want without having to change the code that evaluates them (functionality) (the core reason for object oriented programming).

Hope I don't lose you in the following explanation. Let's start with declaring the **Instruction** and **Call** abstract classes.

```
public abstract class Call {
String name;

public Call(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

public String evaluate(){
    return this.name;
}

 }

public abstract class Instruction {
String name;

public Instruction(String name){
    this.name=name;
}

public String evaluate(){
    return this.name;
}   
}
```

I've placed very basic functionality just to see that it works. Now let's create a couple of different classes that extend from Instruction and Call, so that we can have something to play with.

```
public class Instruction1 extends Instruction {

public Instruction1(String name) {
    super(name);
}

}

public class Call1 extends Call {

public Call1(String name) {
    super(name);
}

}
```

I'm not going to post all the classes because it's got the same code as the Instruction1 and Call1. So the classes I created were: **Instruction1, Instruction2, Instruction3,Call1, Call2, Call3.**

Now that we have that, we're going to create the class that is in charge of handling the correct call of the combination **(instruction, call)**. Your evaluator, if you will.

```
public class InstructionCallsEvaluator {
public String evaluate(Instruction1 instruction, Call1 call){
    return this.evaluate( (Instruction) instruction, (Call) call);
}

public String evaluate(Instruction1 instruction, Call2 call){
    return this.evaluate( (Instruction) instruction, (Call) call);
}

public String evaluate(Instruction1 instruction, Call3 call){
    return this.evaluate( (Instruction) instruction, (Call) call);
}

public String evaluate(Instruction2 instruction, Call1 call){
    return this.evaluate( (Instruction) instruction, (Call) call);
}

public String evaluate(Instruction2 instruction, Call2 call){
    return this.evaluate( (Instruction) instruction, (Call) call);
}

public String evaluate(Instruction2 instruction, Call3 call){
    return this.evaluate( (Instruction) instruction, (Call) call);
}

public String evaluate(Instruction3 instruction, Call1 call){
    return this.evaluate( (Instruction) instruction, (Call) call);
}

public String evaluate(Instruction3 instruction, Call2 call){
    return this.evaluate( (Instruction) instruction, (Call) call);
}

public String evaluate(Instruction3 instruction, Call3 call){
    return this.evaluate( (Instruction) instruction, (Call) call);
}

private String evaluate(Instruction instruction, Call call){
    return instruction.evaluate() + "  " + call.evaluate();
}
}
```

Quite long eh? Here is where you'd be adding all the combinations possible. So if you were to add a new Class# , you'd have to come to this **evaluator** and add the corresponding combination. *You could view this as a downside if compared to the **Command pattern** implementation.*

The reason why I added the `private String evaluate(Instruction instruction, Call call)` is because if formatting of output changed, I'd only have to change this method, and not all the other methods.

Also, the reason why I upcast the method parameters before calling this method is because otherwise you'll get a never ending loop resulting in a stackOverflow Exception:

```
public String evaluate(Instruction3 instruction, Call1 call){
    return this.evaluate(instruction, call);
}
```

If I were to leave it like this and execute, when it calls the **this.evaluate(...)** it'll end up recalling `public String evaluate(Instruction3 instruction, Call1 call)` in a never ending loop.

The reason why I am showing this way of implementation is because I assume for some reason you want to identify what kind of combination **Instruction, call** makes. Otherwise, I'd go with the **Command Pattern.**

Obviously, what I do inside the **evaluate(...)**** is very simple because I don't know exactly what you are trying to do. You'd have to adapt this to your situation.

Now that the handler is set up, let's go for the class that is in charge of calling it properly without **if elses** and **switches**. Your Handler, if you will.

```
public class InstructionHandler {

public String evaluate(Instruction instruction, Call call) {
    try {
        return  useEvaluator(InstructionCallsEvaluator.class, instruction, call);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | 
             InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InstructionHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return "Something went wrong when calling Evaluator";
}


private String useEvaluator(Class<InstructionCallsEvaluator> instructionCallsEvalutor, Instruction instruction, Call call) 
                    throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, 
                    InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {    
    Class[] methodParameterTypes = new Class[]{instruction.getClass(), call.getClass()};
    Object instance = instructionCallsEvalutor.newInstance();
    Method method = instructionCallsEvalutor.getDeclaredMethod("evaluate", methodParameterTypes);
    return  method.invoke(instance, instruction, call).toString();
}
```

}

Let's go through this step by step. All calls will come to

```
`public String evaluate(Instruction instruction, Call call)`
```

which has the **abstract classes** as parameters. Once in there, it has to call the appropriate **evaluate(...)** method of the class **InstructionCallsEvaluator**. The reason why I separated it in two methods is to have the `try{} catch{}` in one and the actual method in the other (cleanliness and readability).

You already know the class whose methods you want to invoke: 
**InstructionCallsEvaluator**, but you don't know which method you are going to invoke. That's where

`private String useEvaluator(Class<InstructionCallsEvaluator> instructionCallsEvalutor, Instruction instruction, Call call)`

comes in.

This method handles the methodParameterTypes, creates an instance of your InstructionCallsEvaluator class, and determines the method that applies to the parameters passed. Once it has got that method, it simply invokes it. Let's try out with this main class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Instruction> instructions = getInstructions();
    ArrayList<Call> calls = getCalls();
    InstructionHandler handler = new InstructionHandler();

    for(Instruction instrct : instructions)
        for(Call call : calls)
            System.out.println(handler.evaluate(instrct, call));
}

private static ArrayList<Instruction> getInstructions(){
    ArrayList<Instruction> instructions = new ArrayList<>();
    instructions.add(new Instruction1("Instruction 1"));
    instructions.add(new Instruction2("Instruction 2"));
    instructions.add(new Instruction3("Instruction 3"));
    return instructions;
}

private static ArrayList<Call> getCalls(){
    ArrayList<Call> calls = new ArrayList<>();
    calls.add(new Call1("Call 1"));
    calls.add(new Call2("Call 2"));
    calls.add(new Call3("Call 3"));
    return calls;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Instruction 1  Call 1
Instruction 1  Call 2
Instruction 1  Call 3
Instruction 2  Call 1
Instruction 2  Call 2
Instruction 2  Call 3
Instruction 3  Call 1
Instruction 3  Call 2
Instruction 3  Call 3
```

You might be wondering why didn't I just skip the whole **InstructionHandler** class altogether and went for:

InstructionCallsEvaluator evaluator = new InstructionCallsEvaluator();
   evaluator.evalute(....);

That's because then I'd have to manually call `evaluator.evalute(....);` with each proper Class and Instruction class, so that my main would look something like this:

```
   evaluator.evalute(new Instruction1(), new Call1());
   evaluator.evalute(new Instruction2(), new Call2());
   ...
```

Rather than being able to call it passing it the upcast of said classes. Of course, this depends on what your goal is, you might just want this, and in that case, you can skip the **InstructionHandler** class altogether.

If you were not to do the `evaluator.evalute(new Instruction1(), new Call1());` and just call it with the upcast, then you'd get a compile time error. You'd have to change the access modifier from

```
    private String evaluate(Instruction instruction, Call call){
    return instruction.evaluate() + "  " + call.evaluate();
}
```

to **public**. But then it would always go through that method, and you'd lose the possibility of knowing what combination of (Instruction, Call) occurred.

Once again, this answer assumes your objective, since I had a bit of a hard time understanding what you want to do. Hope it helps either you, or anyone looking into this question.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) might work for you. You'll need to write more classes though, but it might result in a cleaner all-around architecture (avoiding conditionals scattered around your code).